# Build a NPM package for browser and server?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, browserify

I have a javacript module that I build with webpack to use in the browser:

```
libraryTarget: 'window'
```

When I import it in node, I get:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Which makes sense.

How can I use this lib for both the browser and the server? Should I do 2 separate builds with 2 separate webpack configurations? If not, what should the libraryTarget be?

Comment: use "unpkg": "dist/my-awesome-lib.min.js" in package.json 
follow this link https://codeburst.io/https-chidume-nnamdi-com-npm-module-in-typescript-12b3b22f0724

Comment: does your lib has to be attached to window/global?

Comment: @PlayMa256 I'm not sure, for the browser it worked well but I could use something else if necessary.